# SIGSEGV error, the code is correct but still not giving any output can someone explain

Tags: debugging, vector, segmentation-fault, frequency

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #include <stack>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iterator>
    #define ll long long    
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        ll t;
        cin >> t;
        while(t--) {
           ll n,k;
           cin >>n >>k;
           vector<ll> arr;
           for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin >>arr[i];
            vector <ll> freq;
           for(int i=1;i<=k;i++) freq.push_back(i);
           ll min=n,val,diff=0,max=0;
            for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
               ll c=count(arr.begin(),arr.end(),freq[i]);
               if(min>c) 
               {min=c;
               val=freq[i];
               }
           }
           if(min==0) max=n;
           else{
               vector<ll> diffarr;
            diffarr.push_back(0);
               for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
               {
                   
                 if(arr[i]==val){
                     diffarr.push_back(i);                     
                      }
               }
               for(int i=0;i<min;i++)
               {
                   diff=diffarr[i+1]-diffarr[i];
                   if(max<diff) max=diff;
               }
           }
            cout <<max <<endl;
                    }
        return 0;
    }
```

The code works fine when input is not taken but as soon as I take input it throws a SIGSEGV error
I have debugged it many times to get rid of all segmentation faults and all kinds of errors. Can someone pls look into it, that would be a gr8 help

Answer (score 0):

> the code is correct

No, it *isn't*. Start with these lines:

```
vector<ll> arr;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin >>arr[i];
```

You declare an *empty* vector `arr`, and immediately try to write to element 0 in that vector.

But the vector is still empty, so there is *no* element 0 in it. On most STL implementations this will crash by trying to write to address 0.

Reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is likely to benefit you. So will learning how to use a debugger.